# remove a word from many places in a long text file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

Suppose I have a file with many lines of the form

```
date time name some stuff
```

where every line may be different except for 'name', which is the same every time, and I want to remove 'name' from every line: is it possible to write a short bash script to achieve this?

Comment: Where does "recursive" come into play here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gilles answer works but it will only remove `name` from standard output. If you want to remove `name` from the file itself then you need:

`sed -i 's/name//' file`

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply :

```
sed 's/name//' file
```

?